# How can I make IMPORTHTML function from Google SS retrieve a table without a custom URL?

Tags: python, html, flask, google-sheets

Thanks for taking the time to read this.

I've been working in a website that takes 3 user inputs, and with that information, process them and generates a table. The thing is, I want the information in the data table to be retrieved by the IMPORTHTML function from Google Spreadsheets. When I use a query parameter to the URL that contains the results of the form submission, I can get Google SS to retrieve the information using that custom link.

However, what I've been trying to achieve is to make it so it retrieves the current data from a one and only URL, without the need of making a custom URL for each usage.

These are my scripts:

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import hashlib
import re
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, FloatField, TextAreaField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, NumberRange


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'mysecretkey'

class MyForm(FlaskForm):
    salt = StringField('Salt', validators=[DataRequired()])
    probability = FloatField('Probability', validators=[DataRequired(), NumberRange(min=0, max=1)])
    data = TextAreaField('Data', validators=[DataRequired()])


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form = MyForm()
    if form.is_submitted():
        salt = form.salt.data
        probability = form.probability.data
        data = form.data.data
        table_data = [(email, branch_decision(email, salt, probability)) for email in split_multiline(data)]
        return render_template('results.html', table_data=table_data, form=form)
    return render_template('index.html', form=form)



# Client-provided function
def branch_decision(input_row: str, salt: str, probability: float):
    return (int(hashlib.md5((salt + input_row).encode("ascii")).hexdigest(), 16) / 2**128) < probability


# Function that splits the data content
def split_multiline(input_text):
    # Use regular expression to split the input using \n, \r\n, or \r as delimiters
    split_pattern = r'[\n\r\t\r\n]+'
    result = re.split(split_pattern, input_text)

    # Remove any leading or trailing whitespace from each element in the list
    result = [item.strip() for item in result]

    return result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=80)
```

results.html template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='styles.css') }}">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Results</h1>
    <h2>Salt: {{ form.salt.data }}</h2>
    <h2>Probability: {{ form.probability.data }}</h2>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Inputs</th>
            <th>Outputs</th>
        </tr>
        {% for email, decision in table_data %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ email }}</td>
            <td>{{ decision }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

index.html template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>RCT Branch Allocation</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='styles.css') }}">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>RCT Branch Allocation</h1>
    <div id="container">
        <form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('index') }}">
            <label for="salt">Salt:</label>
            <input type="text" name="salt" id="salt" required>
            <br>
            <label for="probability">Probability:</label>
            <input type="number" name="probability" id="probability" step="any" min="0" max="1" required>
            <br>
            <label for="data">Data:</label>
            <textarea name="data" id="data" rows="4" required></textarea>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm kinda new to coding, so if any of this hurts your sight, I'm sorry.

I tried making everything work under one route, and it does, but when it comes to data retrieval, IMPORTHTML says it's empty.